# Show/hide different Widgets like button, checkbox etc

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a layout which has 5 button placed horizontally.
When I click on the button1 I need to show/hide three checkboxes under button1 and when I click on button2 I need to show/hide three EditText under button2 so on i.e. I need to show/hide different widgets under the button when a button is clicked.

Can any please tell me how to do this.
I apologize if my question is not clear. It is just like expanding and collapsing different views when a button is pressed.

What if I use include tag?

Thanks

Comment: `myControl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE|INVISIBLE|GONE);`?

Comment: I tried this but i was getting a warning saying that there are lot views in the xml which may result in bad performance.

Comment: I can't tell it, since I don't see your layout. However, it's a good practice to limit your views in a layout. Anyway, you don't have to set the visibility for all 6 controls: place each group of 3 in a layout and set the visibility of this container.

Comment: Is there any way to add/hide views or a layout dynamically under the button?

Comment: You could, but the problem remains. And you'd add more stress to the CPU. Not even to say that you'd complicate the logic of your app. For no real benefit.

Comment: "place each group of 3 in a layout and set the visibility of this container" If i use this then I am able to see a warning "Bad performance" because I have lot of views.

Comment: Well, I can't see your layout so I can't tell you what to fix. For instance, if you have an ImageView next to a TextView, you can get rid of the imageView and put the drawable inside the TextView (best practice).

Comment: Post your layout and code what you tried